# Slony sync to 14 slaves, 13 slave works great, but 1 slave slow

Tags: slony

I setup Slony on my 15 machines, all slon --version is 2.2.2, I download source code and compile the slon and slonik by myself.

1 Master and 14 Slaves, the slaves are located at diff office and connection are all via internet

13 slaves works great, synced almost in no time.

1 slave behave wired, this wired slave can sync with Master but seems delay for hours

for example, one tabled named "accounts", all other slaves are synced, this wired slave is not until 30mins~3hours later.

I know there is a parameter slon -l lag interval, but I do not use the lag parameter

and iostate, htop, are seems normal.

I found below WARNING message and google this message but in vain, no helpful

```
05/09 15:37:03 ubuntu@slave:/var/log/postgresql$ sudo tail postgresql-9.1-main.log
2014-05-09 15:30:19 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:30:35 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:30:39 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:34:08 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:35:06 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:35:17 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:35:22 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:35:42 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:36:02 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-05-09 15:36:42 CST WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
```

Is there any thing I can check for this wired slave ?